# Find neighbours of neighbours in a graph using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, graph-theory

I have a matrix `A`, which represents a neighbourhood relationship.

```
A=[1 2
   1 4
   2 6
   4 5
   6 7
   6 8]
```

The rows of `A` are sorted, meaning `[1 2]` and `[2 1]` are considered as the same neighbourhood relationship and the rows of `A` are sorted in ascending lexicographic order.

In our example matrix, node `1` is a neighbour of node `2` and `4`, node `2` is a neighbour of `6`, node `4` is a neighbour of `5`, and so forth. I want to compute a matrix `B` that represents the neighbours of neighbour(NON) relationship. Two nodes are NONs of each other if they both have some node they are both neighbours of. This means `1` is a NON of `5` (via `4`) and `6` (via `2`), etc.

```
 B=[1 5
    1 6
    2 4
    2 7
    2 8
    7 8]
```

How can I compute the matrix `B`?

Answer (score 5):

Let's call your graph `G`. You could compute the neighbors to neighbors of `G` by using the [*graph power*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_power) `G^k` for `k=2`, which is the graph that has the same nodes, but in which two vertices are adjacent when their distance in `G` is at most `k`.

You can read the details on the wikipedia article, but the most important part is:

> If `A` is an adjacency matrix for the graph, modified to have nonzero
>   entries on its main diagonal, then the nonzero entries of `A^k` give the
>   adjacency matrix of the `k`th power of the graph.

(For our case `k=2` we won't need nonzero entries on the diagonal, as we need distance exactly two and not distance *smaller or equal* to two, which setting the diagonal to nonzero entries is for.)

So you simply build your adjacency matrix `A` by:

```
edges = A;
n = max(edges(:));
A = sparse(edges(:,1),edges(:,2),1,n,n) + ...
    sparse(edges(:,2),edges(:,1),1,n,n); % Make graph undirected via symmetry.
```

You will then generate the adjacency matrix of `G^2` via `A*A` or `A^2`, which you then use `find` on to get the edges:

```
[I,J] = find(A^2); % Edges of A^2
```

You can then build `B` by removing the elements you don't want in there (like the original connections or self-connections)

```
B = setdiff(sort([I,J],2), [edges; [(1:n).',(1:n).'], 'rows')
```

Comment: Nice.  Here I was trying to do it by brute-force. +1.

Comment: BTW, I would place that NB at the very beginning.  It's basically a `tl;dr` for those who don't want to read the Wiki article.  Just a minor suggestion of course.  Either way, this is a great answer.